# Zenbook ux433fn activate illuminated numpad

Tags: asus, numpad

Hello I´m new in the forum so this ist my first question :)
I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my new Zenbook ux433fn with used to have a new fancy illuminated numpad in the touchpad. Like I expected it doesn´t work with Ubuntu and I wounder if it is possible to add the functionality?

Comment: Does no one has an idea?

Comment: Would be also interested. I am considering buying ux433fn, but would not like to see that such feature is not yet supported. As an off-topic can I ask you if all other features are working fine on Ubuntu ?

Comment: The only things I have noticed are a pretty high battety drain in sleep Mode and that the Fn-lock (fn +Esc) ist not working. First issue can be solved by setting up suspend Mode when lid is closing. But I was unable to get the fn-lock working.

Comment: Any solution?
I'm having the same problem.

Comment: You might push for this bug to be resolved. Other than that, I would not expect this feature to work: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1810183

Comment: the fn-lock works in kernel 5.2.x (I'm on 5.2.7 on Fedora)

Answer (score 1):

Just install this driver

https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver

ux581l works on my expertbook

Answer (score 1):

I maintain latest & most featured version of Asus numpad/touchpad driver. Link https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers/asus-touchpad-numpad-driver. If any problems persist, please contact me via github contact e-mail or create issue on github repository. If you use laptop Asus WMI hotkeys (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> keys) or Asus accessories like stylus you might be interested in other drivers https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers, install them in the same way as numpad one.